# Calculate moving geometric mean by water sampling station

Tags: r, dplyr, trend

I need to calculate the moving geometric mean on fecal coliform over time(at each value I want the geomean of that value and the previous 29 values), by individual sampling stations.  When I download the data from our database the column headers are:

```
Station SampleDate FecalColiform
```

Depending on the growing area there are a few to over a dozen stations.

I tried to adapt some code that I found at [HERE](https://rpubs.com/Andy_Hrycyna/76172):

```
#File: Fecal
Fecal <- group_by(Fecal, Station) %>%
arrange(SampleDate) %>%
mutate(logres = log10(ResultValue)) %>%
mutate(mgm = stats::filter(logres, rep(1/24, 24), sides =1))
```

This worked, but the problem is that I don't want the resulting log values.  I want just the regular geomean so that I can plot it and everyone can easily understand the values.  I tried to somehow sneak the geometric.mean function from the psych package in there I could not make that work.

There are resources for calculating a moving average, and code for calculating geometric mean and I have tried to combine several of them. I can't find an example for moving geometric mean.

Eventually I would like to graph all of geomeans by station similar to the example in the link above.

```
> dput(ByStationRGMData[1:10,])

structure(list(Station = c(114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 
114L, 114L, 114L, 114L), Classification = structure(c(3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("  Approved  ", "  Conditionally        Approved  ", 
"  Prohibited  "), class = "factor"), SampleDate = c(19890103L, 
19890103L, 19890209L, 19890316L, 19890413L, 19890511L, 19890615L, 
19890713L, 19890817L, 19890914L), SWTemp = c(NA, NA, 5L, 8L, 
NA, 13L, 15L, 18L, NA, 18L), Salinity = c(NA, NA, 22L, 18L, NA, 
26L, 22L, 24L, NA, 32L), FecalColiform = c(180, 49, 2, 17, 7.9, 
1.8, 4.5, 11, 33, 1.8), RGM = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
)), .Names = c("Station", "Classification", "SampleDate", "SWTemp", 
"Salinity", "FecalColiform", "RGM"), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), vars = list(
Station), drop = TRUE, indices = list(0:9), group_sizes = 10L,      biggest_group_size = 10L, labels = structure(list(
Station = 114L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), vars = list(Station), drop = TRUE, .Names = "Station"))
```

I would also like to add a moving 90th percentile to the dataframe and the graphs.  I tried the following:

```
ByStationRGMData <- RawData %>%
group_by(Station) %>%
arrange(SampleDate) %>%
mutate(RGM = as.numeric(rollapply(FecalColiform, 30, geometric.mean,     fill=NA, align="right"))) +
mutate(F90 = as.numeric(rollapply(FecalColiform, 30, quantile, p=0.90, fill=NA, align="right")))
```

This gives me the error:

> Error in mutate_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : argument ".data" is missing, with no default

I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: The log of the geometric mean is the arithmetic mean of the logs of the values. So, after calculating the moving (arithmetic) mean of the log-values you have to inverse per `exp(...)` to get the geometric mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rollapply` from the `zoo` package (illustrated here using the built-in `mtcars` data frame). I've used a window of 3 values, but you can set that to 30 in your actual data. `align="left"` uses the current value and n-1 previous values, where n is the window width:

```
library(psych)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(mpgGM = rollapply(mpg, 3, geometric.mean, fill=NA, align="left"))
```

Include a grouping variable to get rolling geometric means separately for each group.

Comment: Thank you, that worked well.  I had to include as.numeric ()  because otherwise it would not work.  Also, it went the wrong direction, starting in 2015 instead of 1989.  I changed the align to "right" and I got an error: wrong sign in 'by' argument.  ???

Comment: Please post a sample of your data (for example, paste the output of `dput(Fecal[1:10,])` to provide the first 10 rows of your data) and the code you ran. You can post this at the end of your question.

Comment: I returned from my Thanksgiving weekend and ran the code again and it worked for some reason.  I still posted a sample as your requested just in case.  I'm also trying to add a rolling 90th percentile if that is something you can help me with.  Thanks for your help.